# How to collapse an element after save is success (Angular+ui.bootstrap)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am a new for Angular, I want to collapse an element having save button inside after save is success. Here is my HTML code,

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="member in members">
       <select ng-model="member.role" ng-options="o as o for o in o" ng-change="isCollapse= false"></select>
       <div collapse="isCollapse">
           <button ng-click="saveMember(member)">Save</button>
           <button ng-click="isCollapse=true">Cancel</button>
       </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And here is my controller,

```
myApp.controller('AccountController', function($scope, AccountService){
    $scope.isCollapse= true;
    $scope.saveMember = function(obj){
        AccountService.saveAccount(obj).success(function(data){
           if(data.status === 'success'){
             //I tried   $scope.isCollapse = true     but it didn't work.
           }
        });
    };
}
```

I can simply do it by use

```
<button ng-click="saveMember(member);isCollapse=true">Save</button>
```

but it will be collapsed without checking the save.

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Hi @Hikaru, what is the attribute **collapse** in your div? is this angular directive?

Comment: @AbhilashPA it is a directive of http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: I can think of two things, first, are you sure your if statement is triggered? and second, if it is, maybe you have to use $scope.$apply() , to update. I am a beginner myself, this is just thoughts

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the success callback I don't see a reason for checking the status again. I believe that the code inside the `if` statement does not fire, so the `isCollapse` variable does not change value.

What I would try out is

```
    AccountService.saveAccount(obj).success(function(data){
       $scope.isCollapse = true;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
 <div collapse="isCollapse || saveSuccess==member.id"> <!--I filled || saveSuccess==member.id here-->
```

and in the controller,

```
AccountService.saveAccount(obj).success(function(data){
   $scope.saveSuccess = obj.id;
});
```

Thank you everyone.